# getText is not working correct

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with JAVA to create automation for my application. 
I have 2 questions. I am trying to get text from the following div but not getting the correct text.
1. I have a button with text as 'OK'. It looks very simple to get the text by getText and doing assertEquals but my test fails.

```
<div id="OK">
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:window.close();" style="width:80px" 
value="OK">
</div>
```

Till now I have tried following sols but nothing works.

```
Text = driver.findElement(By.id("OK")).getText();
```

and

```
Text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'OK']//input[@value = 'OK']")).getText();
```

and I am comparing with assertEquals. Following is the assertError I am getting:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
expected [OK] but found []
```

The second text I am trying to get is from the following:

```
<div id="PartNo">
Part #
<span id="lblPartNo">   11-222-33</span>
<br>
<a id="btn_version" 
href="javascript:__doPostBack('btn_version','')">VersionTestDetails</a>
</div>
```

I want to get only "Part #" but my code is getting the complete text for div i.e.

```
"Part #   11-222-33  
VersionTextDetails".
```

I have intentionally added an enter after "33" because that how I am getting data. 
Following sols I tries but nothing works to get "Part #"

```
Text = driver.findElement(By.id("PartNo")).getText();
```

And

```
Text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id = 'content']//div[contains(text(), 'Part #')]")).getText();
```

After getting the text I am doing assertEquals but get the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
expected [Part #   11-222-33 VersionTestDetails] but found [Part #   11-222-33 VersionTestDetails]
```

I have confirmed in both the above cases the id or xpath I am using is correct.
Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: use css selector.

Comment: 1. Use getAttribute("value") instead of getText() as 'OK' is defined in the value attribute. 2. The css or xpath should be getting the text from inside the span and not containing div. Regarding the extra space remove them using pattern matching or maybe the space is just as designed and you need to change the expected criterion.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text from button, use getAttribute instead of getText.

```
String value= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#OK input")).getAttribute("value");
```

In the second case, it is the actual behavior. YOu'll get the entire inner text of those elements. After getting the entire text from that div you can modify it before using it in assert.

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.id("PartNo")).getText();
assertEquals(true, text.contains("Part #"));
```

Comment: The first works perfect. I am able to get the OK button text. But the second one is not the approach I am looking for because I have one expected properties file from where I am comparing my result with my actual result and the code looks like: softAssert.assertEquals( loginpage.popUpWindowPartNumberLabelText, readpropertiesfiles.expectedProperties.getProperty("loginPagePopUpWindowPartNumberLabelText"));

Comment: In continuation with above:The loginpage.popUpWindowPartNumberLabelText = Part #   11-222-33
VersionTestDetails AND readpropertiesfiles.expectedProperties.getProperty("loginPagePopUpWindowPartNumberLabelText")  = Part #   11-222-33                                              The problem is I cannot put expected result data as Part #   11-222-33
VersionTestDetails because properties file will not count VersionTextDetails as part of Part #   11-222-33

Comment: Tried softAssert.assertEquals(true, loginpage.popUpWindowPartNumberLabelText.contains(readpropertiesfiles.expectedProperties.getProperty("loginPagePopUpWindowPartNumberLabelText")), "Part Number doesnot match..."); but get AssertError as java.lang.AssertionError: The following asserts failed:
 expected [Part #   11-222-33] but found [Part #   11-222-33
VersionTestDetails] also tried softAssert.assertTrue(loginpage.popUpWindowPartNumberLabelText.matches(readpropertiesfiles.expectedProperties.getProperty("loginPagePopUpWindowPartNumberLabelText")), "Part Number not found"); but test fail

Comment: Can you print (Using System.out.println)below two value and check
1. loginpage.popUpWindowPartNumberLabelText  2. readproper‌​tiesfiles.expectedPr‌​operties.getProperty‌​("loginPagePopUpWind‌​owPartNumberLabelTex‌​t") . I guess, some line break is there in actual text between Part # and 11-222-33. check that out

Answer (score 0):

It will not work with getText() since it is defined as value in DOM

```
String value= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#OK input")).getAttribute("value");
```